# Launch Process comand from a controller - Symfony 2.1

Tags: php, symfony

I have a doubt launching a command process from my controller. The command process work fine from command line, and from my controller works using 
    MyProcess->run();
but not works
    MyProcess->start()
I don't understand why!

I need launch it in background (asynchronously) and i would need use start()

```
//Launch process 
$process = new Process('php ../app/console preinscripciones:enviar');
$process->start();//not work using start but it does it if I use run()

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new \RuntimeException($process->getErrorOutput());
}
echo  $process->getOutput();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any errors in php log or on screen? And also check `$process->isRunning()` after `$process->start()`;

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support! if I add while ($process->isRunning()) in my code it works!! but then is not asynchronous!! :) What is happening? I don't understand!

Comment: Have you got php-fpm installed ?

Comment: No, but the main problem is that I don't know why the process starts only if I add $process->isRunning().

Comment: I think, it was always working. Maybe you missed something